# Trocar o selected de uma option que esta em script de copia

Tags: javascript

Sou nova na área e estou com muitas dificuldades para fazer o seguinte:

1. Fiz uma script em javascript para criar diversas cópias do meu `option`. Até aí tudo bem: cópias efetuadas com sucesso.
2. Preciso fazer um `for` em javascript para percorrer cada `option` copiado e deixar à mostra na primeira linha uma frase diferente para cada `option`.

Pensei o seguinte:

- `for` que percorre o `option`
- Procurando a frase x em um `option` qualquer
- Achou a frase x no `option`: acrescenta um `selected`, para que a frase apareça como primeira opção da `option`.

Segue abaixo código teste de um html com a função copia, para melhor entendimento:

```html
<!-- ... <html>, <head>, jQuery, etc ... -->
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Lixo01</td>
        <td class="Original" id="Linha1">
            <select id="MaxAlarme3">
                <option value="02">Teste1</option>
                <option value="03">Teste2</option>
                <option value="0">Teste3</option>
                <option value="04">Teste4</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lixo02 teste</td>
        <td class="Clonar" id="Linha2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lixo03 value 05</td>
        <td class="Clonar" id="Linha3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lixo04</td>
        <td class="Clonar" id="Linha4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lixo05</td>
        <td class="Clonar" id="Linha5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lixo06</td>
        <td class="Clonar" id="Linha6"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    //variavel contar o tamanho das copias
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Copia valor da Linha1.Classe
        var Copiar = $("#Linha1.Original").html();
        //Clona o valor da Linha 1 para a Classe Clonar
        $(".Clonar").append(Copiar);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Poste o código em que você tenha tentado fazer isso.

Comment: Não entendi bem... tu quer só setar o OPTION que vai estar selecionado no SELECT?

Comment: Bom dia. Silvio Andorinha, então não posso postar o código, noemas da empresa :(

Comment: Bom dia  Daniel T. Sobrosa.Eu quero que cada option copiado se inicie com uma frase diferente. Vou postar um html teste para que vcs possam entender melhor, pois não posso postar o código original.

Comment: @user5946, quando for colocar algum código, selecione ele e click no icone **{ }** para formatado-lo.

Comment: Por que eu gosto que postem o código no JSFiddle: primeira coisa que faço é apertar o TidyUp.

Comment: A obrigado séculos luz dps, consegui postar o html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui o que eu queriaaa eeee.

```
// frase que desejo localizar
    var frase      = "04";//eu queria que a variavel frase pegasse o value dos options e de acordo com o valor do
    //option eu poderia escolher a frase que iria iniciar o mesmo
       var localizado = null;

    // loop que percorre cada uma das opções
    // e verifica se a frase da opção confere com o
    // valor de fase que está sendo procurado
    $('#Linha6 option').each(function() {
      // se localizar a frase, define o atributo selected
      if($(this).attr('value') == frase) {//-----Alterei de $(this).value() para o attr.()-----
        $(this).prop('selected', true); //-----Pode-se utilizar .attr('selected', true) também-----
      }
    });
```

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<select id="opcoes">
    <option>Selecione</option>
    <option>Lorem ipsum Cupidatat sunt exercitation fugiat Excepteur.</option>
    <option>Lorem ipsum Elit sint velit nostrud minim quis.</option>
    <option>Lorem ipsum Id cillum est dolor.</option>
    <option>Lorem ipsum Irure Ut veniam cupidatat dolor culpa.</option>
    <option>Lorem ipsum Pariatur et Duis cupidatat.</option>
    <option>Lorem ipsum Esse laboris veniam irure eu irure.</option>
    <option>Lorem ipsum Anim eu culpa magna quis irure.</option>
    <option>Lorem ipsum Dolore Excepteur esse aliquip Duis eu.</option>
    <option>Lorem ipsum Duis ut velit non.</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // frase que desejo localizar
    var frase      = "Lorem ipsum Dolore Excepteur esse aliquip Duis eu.",
        localizado = null;

    // loop que percorre cada uma das opções
    // e verifica se a frase da opção confere com o
    // valor de fase que está sendo procurado
    $('#opcoes option').each(function() {
      // se localizar a frase, define o atributo selected
      if($(this).text() == frase) {
        $(this).attr('selected', true);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Oiii descobri o que eu estava errando o seu código esta certinho. Agora vou tentar adaptar eu meu. Obrigada

Comment: Outra coisa se possível eu preciso chamar as frases pelo value. Pode me mandar um exemplo?Grata.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, uma maneira de manter seu código mais limpo, seria usando a o método $.find conforme abaixo:

HTML

```
<select id="opcoes">
  <option value="0">Selecione</option>
  <option value="1">Lorem ipsum Cupidatat sunt exercitation fugiat Excepteur.</option>
  <option value="2">Lorem ipsum Elit sint velit nostrud minim quis.</option>
  <option value="3">Lorem ipsum Id cillum est dolor.</option>
  <option value="4">Lorem ipsum Irure Ut veniam cupidatat dolor culpa.</option>
  <option value="5">Lorem ipsum Pariatur et Duis cupidatat.</option>
  <option value="6">Lorem ipsum Esse laboris veniam irure eu irure.</option>
  <option value="7">Lorem ipsum Anim eu culpa magna quis irure.</option>
  <option value="8">Lorem ipsum Dolore Excepteur esse aliquip Duis eu.</option>
  <option value="9">Lorem ipsum Duis ut velit non.</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // valor que desejo localizar
  var value = "1";

  // Usa-se o método $.find para buscar a
  // opção pelo atributo value e o seleciona
  $('#opcoes').find('[value="' + value + '"]').attr('selected', true);
});
```

Comment: Ok obrigado, assim que possível vou testar e te falo

Answer (score 0):

Não precisa percorrer o select, com uma simples linha dá pra fazer isso!

HTML

```
<select id="cores">
    <option>Selecione</option>
    <option value='1'>Vermelho</option>
    <option value='2'>Azul</option>
    <option value='3'>Verde</option>
</select>
```

JQuery (Selecionar a cor azul)

```
$("#cores>option[value=2]").attr("selected", true);
```